# will_pagination work locally but not on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, pagination

I'm new to rails and try on a sample from agile development with rails,
after that I'm trying add paginate through will_paginate,
it works fine on local but not on heroku, 
here's my heroku link:
http://squarer-bookshop.herokuapp.com/
the paginate just don't work, the page stayed the same after pagination clicked.
I'm simply doing :

```
def index
  @products = Product.paginate(:per_page => 4, :page => params[:page]).order('title')   
end
```

and in index.html.erb

```
<%= will_paginate @products %>
```

any suggestion is appreciated!

Comment: This would be standard behaviour if you have will_paginate gem installed on your system but not bundled in your gemfile. Have you added "gem 'will_paginate'" in your gemfile?

Comment: Also, put the paginate method last, after "order(..)"

Comment: I do have "gem 'will_paginate'" in my gemfile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it today it happened coz I have <% cache do %> in index page,
just remove it or disable cache in production.rb

```
config.action_controller.perform_caching = false
```